Would the category of directed sets be better behaved with the empty set included, or excluded?
In a topology book of mine, a directed set is defined as a nonempty set $D$ equipped with a relation $R$ that is transitive, reflexive, and for all elements $x$ and $y$ of $D$, there exists a $z$ in $D$ such that both $xRz$ and $yRz$.
Would the category of directed sets be better behaved with the empty set included, or excluded?
The empty set equipped with the empty relation satisfies all three conditions of the definitions, vacuously. I think this is a similar scenario to when some books require a magma to be nonempty, or a metric space to be nonempty, or a topological space to be nonempty. However, I believe allowing the empty set in those categories of things gives those same categories better properties, such as having initial and/or terminal objects.

No, a directed set cannot be empty.
This situation is not like the other ones you name. The point of this definition is that a directed set has a direction (that's why it's called that); it is "going somewhere." For example $(\mathbb{N}, \le)$ as a directed set is "going towards $\infty$." In topology directed sets are used to define nets, which are functions from a directed set to a topological space $X$, and these eneralize sequences (which are nets of shape $(\mathbb{N}, \le)$). They have a notion of convergence which generalizes convergent sequences, which relies on this idea that a directed set is "going somewhere."
The empty set is not going anywhere! It does not have a direction.

I think this is also yet another example of too simple to be simple. A directed set ought to be defined as a preorder $(X,\le)$ such that if $x_1,\dots,x_n\in X$, then there is a $z\in X$ such that $x_i\le z$ for all integers $i$ satisfying $1\le i\le n$. In the case $n=0$, this amounts to asking that $X$ is nonempty. (This definition has the advantage of avoiding the bias towards $2$-ary operations that often leads to awkward conventions and definitions.)

@user105952: the point of the definition is simply not to study the category of directed sets. The category of directed sets does not matter. Even in pure category theory, which also uses directed sets, directed sets are only used as shapes of diagrams to define directed colimits and codirected limits.

But, yes, if you allowed the empty set to be directed then the category of directed sets would have an initial object, and otherwise it doesn't.

Wouldn't this argument discard also directed sets with only one element?

@jjagmath: no, that one is "going to" its single element. More generally any finite directed set has a greatest element and finite directed sets are "going to" that element.

If a directed set could be empty, we would not have things like "every net in a compact space has a convergent subnet," because a net with empty domain cannot converge.

The empty set is of course a pre-ordered set, though not a very interesting one. Is it a directed set?
In the literature one can find two definitions of a directed set.
Definition  1. A directed set is a pre-ordered set $D$ such that every pair of elements has an upper bound.
Definition  2. A directed set is a pre-ordered set $D$ such that every finite subset has an upper bound.
In the sense of definition 1 the empty set is directed, in the sense of definition 2 it is not (the empty subset does not have an upper bound).
Clearly a directed set in the sense of definition 2 is a directed set in the sense of definition 1. The converse holds if and only if the set is non-empty.
In other words, for non-empty sets both definitions agree.
Each pre-ordered set which has a maximum is directed, but that is in some sense a trivial case.
For finite non-empty sets the concept of being directed is fairly uninteresting. In fact, a non-empty finite set is directed if and only if it is has a maximum.
Thus only infinite directed sets $D$ without a maximum are really interesting because they have a "direction towards an element $\infty$ outside of $D$".
In fact, taking any element $\infty \notin D$, we can define $\bar D = D \cup \{\infty\}$ and extend the pre-order $\le$ on $D$ to $\bar D$ via $d \le \infty$ for all $d \in D$. Then $\bar D$ is a directed set which has a maximum (namely $\infty$).

The "real" definition of a directed poset is: each finite subset has an upper bound. Note that "each finite subset" in particular includes the empty set.
This is equivalent to requiring that the set is non-empty and each pair of elements has an upper bound. This is often stated as the official definition, but the "real" definition is the one that talks about all finite subsets.

My real question is, would the category of directed sets be better behaved with the empty set included, or excluded?

The categorical behavior of directed posets is quite irrelevant because while directed posets are extremely important in mathematics, their importance does not at all stem from the category of directed posets. For all practical purposes the category of directed posets (unlike, for example, the category of dcpos) does not appear anywhere in mathematics. It would be a very bad design choice to say that the empty set should be counted as directed just because it would furnish the category of directed sets with an initial object, simply because no-one cares whether this category has an initial object and its having an initial object does not come up in actual mathematics.
For example, it is an important fact that continuous maps are precisely those which preserve limits of nets (which are maps from directed sets into a topological space, viewed as generalization of sequences), but this has nothing at all to do with the behavior of the category of directed posets. Indeed, allowing for the empty directed set would be wrong in this context, because it does not make sense to talk about the limit of the empty net (even in spaces where all other limits exist).
